# How to pass custom data to the log4net.Core.LoggingEvent object?

Tags: c#, log4net, mstest, testcontext

I want to get custom data from the `log4net.Core.LoggingEvent` object inside `Append` method of my custom `log4net` appender.

```
public sealed class SimpleAppender : AppenderSkeleton
{
    protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        // How can I receive my data?
    }
}
```

I know that `log4net.Core.LoggingEvent` contains `Properties` property. It has type `log4net.Util.PropertiesDictionary`. A logger or an appender may attach additional properties to specific events, but I'm not sure that it is what the way I'm looking for. I need to get `testId` here. I created that `testId` in the method marked `[TestInitialize]` attribute.

```
public class UnitTest1
{
    public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        Guid testId = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        ApplicationLogger.LogInfo("TestMethod1 has started.");
    }       
}
```

`ApplicationLogger` class is a simple `log4net`logger wrapper which prints result into console. I know that I can do something like this.

```
ApplicationLogger.LogInfo("Test message", testId);

public static class ApplicationLogger
{
    private static readonly log4net.ILog log4netLogger;

    public static void LogInfo(Guid testId, string infoMessage)
    {
        ApplicationLogger.log4netLogger.Info(new LogMessageModel
        {
            Text = infoMessage,
            TestId = testId
        });
    }
}
```

But I don't want to set `testId` into `LogInfo()` method every time I need to log something. Is there another more more elegant way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add a static Initialize() function to ApplicationLogger that accepts testId as a parameter and call ApplicationLogger.Initialize(testId) from UnitTest1.Initialize()?

Answer (score 0):

Add a static `Initialize()` function to `ApplicationLogger` that accepts testId as a parameter and call `ApplicationLogger.Initialize(testId)` from `UnitTest1.Initialize()`.